# wxwidgets listctrl can't see title when using wxsmith in codeblocks

Tags: codeblocks, wxwidgets, listctrl

[image]

As the picture shows, you can't find the title which should be "Column 1","Column 2","Column 3"

Here is what I am doing:

1. In Constructor

   ```
   ListCtrlRevMsg = new wxListCtrl(this, ID_LISTCTRL1, wxPoint(72,8),wxSize(330,100), wxLC_REPORT, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_LISTCTRL1"));
   ```
2. And then, init the columns

   ```
   wxListItem itemCol;

   itemCol.SetText(wxT("Column 1"));
   itemCol.SetImage(-1);
   itemCol.SetWidth(100);
   itemCol.SetTextColour(*wxRED);
   ListCtrlRevMsg->InsertColumn(0, itemCol);

   itemCol.SetText(wxT("Column 2"));
   ListCtrlRevMsg->InsertColumn(1, itemCol);

   itemCol.SetText(wxT("Column 3"));
   ListCtrlRevMsg->InsertColumn(2, itemCol);
   ```

I can't find the reason.

Comment: I can't upload a picture now, so there is a link of the picture.

Comment: This definitely works with wxW 3.1.0, so which wxW version are you using ?
Can you reproduce it in minimal sample ?

Comment: The wxW version is 3.02, and there is listctrl sample in the samples directory. When i copy the sorces in the 2 step to the listctrl sample, for the initial of the list, it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I find the reason: 
    itemCol.SetImage(-1);
because i don't init the images, when i remove this sentence，it works fine.